# jQuery not looping at my second condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, loops

I have a code that fetches location data if its found and keeps refreshing every 5 seconds which works great (Only if the location is found). However, when there's a problem at fetching I have put an error message "Cannot fetch.." but jQuery never seems to refresh again if this message shows up.. Any idea about how to fix this issue? Appreciate any inputs or suggestions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lookup_time = 5000; 
  var animation_time = 1000;
  var elapsed_realtime = null;
  var ajax_timeout = 20000; // 30 Seconds before ajax fails
  $(document.body).fadeIn(animation_time);
  (function get_location() {
    if(elapsed_realtime != null) {
      clearInterval(elapsed_realtime);
    }
    $('#map_view,#elapsed_timer').fadeOut(0);
    $('#locate_me').fadeOut(0).html('').fadeIn(animation_time); /*Fetching*/
    $('#fetch_me').fadeIn(1000);
    $('#cannot_me').fadeOut(0);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/locate/locate.php',
      timeout: ajax_timeout,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#locate_me').fadeOut(0);

        if(data['location'] == undefined) {
          $('#locate_me').fadeOut(0)
          .html('') /*Cannot fetch data at this time, try again later.*/
          .fadeIn(animation_time);
          $('#cannot_me').fadeIn(1000);
          $('#fetch_me').fadeOut(0);
          return; /////////////// It never Re-fetches after this return//////////////////
        }
        $('#locate_me').fadeOut(0)
          .html(data['location'])
          .fadeIn(animation_time);
        $('#fetch_me').fadeOut(0);
        $('#map_view').prop('href',data['map']);
        $('#map_view').fadeIn(animation_time);
        $('#elapsed_timer').fadeIn(3000);
        elapsed_realtime = setInterval(function() { get_elapsed(data['time'])}, 500);
        //setTimeout(clearInterval(elapsed_realtime),lookup_time);
        setTimeout(get_location,lookup_time);
      }
    });
  }());
});
```

Comment: Why should it re-fetch? You only make the `setTimeout()` call at the end of the function, *after* that `return` statement.

Comment: So where should I put the set-Timout()? I thought It should be at the end so it loops through the whole code?

Comment: A `return` statement exits the function immediately. Once you hit that `return` nothing else in the function will run. It looks to me as if you want to put that `setTimeout()` call right before that `return` statement, and not at the end of the whole function. If you get the end, that means you succeeded in getting the location information, right?

Comment: Yes the end means that I got the location and it prints it in .html(data['location']). So If I put the setTimout before the return would that stop it from getting to the end in any case? I just want it to treat the error as a normal text location and it refreshes regardless of an error or a success.

Comment: Then it will be better to remove `return` and wrap code below it (except `setTimeout`) with `else {}`

Comment: Thanks Regent! Worked perfectly!